# Create an if statement based on page_id

Tags: php, pages

I'm creating custom content and I want to show different content based on my page ID.

For example, in home page I don't want to show anything but in another page I want to fill that space with some text and in other different page I want to fill the same space but with different text.

In my page.php is where I want to put this "IF" statement as follow:

```
IF (is_home) {display nothing }
ELSE IF (is_page_id=1111) {display text01} 
ELSE IF (is_page_id=2222) {display text02}
```

How can I control this using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `if (is_home)` - the homepage doesn't use `page.php` as a template, and you're checking for page ID anyway, which the homepage shouldn't match. To check what page you're on you can use `is_page()` with the page ID.

```
if(is_page(1111)) { display text 01; }
elseif(is_page(2222)) { display text 02; }
```

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine, this simple solution works fine for me! :)